# Create a csv from a variable length newline input

Tags: bash, awk

Seems like a simple one but i've been playing for a bit and can not find something elegant!

So I have data like this:

```
Field1 09:30
Field2 H
Field3 Happy
Field1 09:35
Field3 Sad
Field1 09:40
Field2 C
Field1 09:45
Field2 P
Field3 Pleased
```

... basically Field1 will always be present and the other fields are optional. I would like to strip this into a csv (sadly I cant use python) so that spaces are left appropriately

```
09:30, H, Happy
09:35, , Sad
09:40, C, 
09:45, P, Pleased
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try with this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=", "}
     p && /Field1/
         {    print a["Field1"], a["Field2"], a["Field3"];
              a["Field1"]=a["Field2"]=a["Field3"]=""
         }
     {a[$1]=$2; p=1}
     END{print a["Field1"], a["Field2"], a["Field3"]}
    ' file
```

It returns:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=", "} p && /Field1/ {print a["Field1"], a["Field2"], a["Field3"]; a["Field1"]=a["Field2"]=a["Field3"]=""} {a[$1]=$2; p=1} END{print a["Field1"], a["Field2"], a["Field3"]}' file
09:30, H, Happy
09:35, , Sad
09:40, C, 
09:45, P, Pleased
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{OFS=", "}` set output field separator to be `,` (comma, space).
- `p && /Field1/ {}` if `p` flag is "on" and the line contains `Field1`, do `{}`
- `print a["Field1"], a["Field2"], a["Field3"];` print the three values of the `a[]` array.
- `a["Field1"]=a["Field2"]=a["Field3"]=""` empty the array.
- `{a[$1]=$2; p=1}` for each line, store the 2nd column values in the `a[]` array. Also, activate the `p` flag so that it will start printing lines when finds next `Field1`.
- `END{print a["Field1"], a["Field2"], a["Field3"]}` print the last piece of data.

Comment: Thanks man, this works great. But two problems! First when I put it into a bash script it acts differently, any ideas why? Also tried to adapt it to my real world script (which has four fields actually) but am not able to get the correct output out

Comment: @mbbxedh2 mmmm make sure you copy & paste it properly. You can also save it in a `script.awk` and run with `awk -f script.awk your_file`. Regarding the real case, have into consideration the need to empty all 4 fields. Try posting something related (in case you do not want to post your real data) so I can guess what can be going wrong. Success!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution in `perl`:

```
perl -lane 'if(/Field([\d])/){
               if($1==1 && $.!=1)
                 {
                  print join ",",@a;
                  undef @a 
                 }
                 $a[$1-1]=$F[1]}
             END{print join ",",@a}' your_file
```

`/Field([\d])/`- The braces around [\d] will capture the number in $1 which can be used as an array index later.

`$a[$1-1]=$F[1]->` store the second field of the line in the array at index captured earlier.

```
if($1==1 && $.!=1)
                 {
                  print join ",",@a;
                  undef @a 
                 }#
```

print the array as soon as the captured decimal is 1 and empty the array.

One array will be left at the end which will be printed in the `END` block.

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
Field1 09:30
Field2 H
Field3 Happy
Field1 09:35
Field3 Sad
Field1 09:40
Field2 C
Field1 09:45
Field2 P
Field3 Pleased
> perl -lane 'if(/Field([\d])/){if($1==1 && $.!=1){print join ",",@a;undef @a }$a[$1-1]=$F[1]}END{print join ",",@a}' temp
09:30,H,Happy
09:35,,Sad
09:40,C
09:45,P,Pleased
>
```

Comment: Yes it is, just capture the decimal after field and use that as an index in an array`$a[$1-1]=$F[1]`. Simple! Is it not?.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the `awk` is not simple. It really is, it is just that the fetching of the data is a bit long. Simple <> short :)

Answer (score 1):

Here comes an alternative with `awk`:

```
# new records always starting with Field1
/Field1/ {
  # print record if it isset
  if(length(r[0])>0) {
    printf "%s, %s, %s\n", r[0], r[1], r[2]
  };  

  # reinitialize record
  r[0]=r[1]=r[2]=""

  # copy value
  r[0]=$2
}

/Field2/ {
  # copy value
  r[1]=$2
}

/Field3/ {
  # copy value
  r[2]=$2
}

# the END block idea comes from @fedorqui. Thanks!
END {
  # print record if it isset
  if(length(r[0])>0) {
    printf "%s, %s, %s\n", r[0], r[1], r[2]
  };  
}
```

Save the script in `csv.awk`. Then execute `awk` like this:

```
awk -f csv.awk input.txt
```

Comment: Yes... it is necessary to add the `END` block to print the last info :) Couldn't find a better way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are fed up with the same kind of data formatting work, like me.
Below is the snippet I use a lot, slightly modified.  You can define as many fields(not necessarily the same pattern) as you like in line 2, and then issue `awk -f so.awk input.txt` (assuming you save this awk snippet in so.awk and your input file is input.txt).

Enjoy:)

```
EGIN {
    FIELD_LIST = "Field1,Field2,Field3"; # fields definition, in order
    split(FIELD_LIST, fields, ",");
}

{
    pos = find(fields, $1);
    if (pos == 0) {
        print("unexpected field " $1);
        exit 1;
    }
    if ($1 == fields[1] && NR>1) { # record start
        echo_record(fields, rec);
        split("", rec)
    }
    rec[$1] = $2; # store field value
}
END {
    echo_record(fields, rec);
}

# find position of val in arr. 0 if not found
function find(arr, val)
{
    i=1;
    for (idx in arr) {
        if (arr[idx] == val) return i;
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}

function echo_record(fileds, record)
{
    start = 0
    for (key in fields) {
        if (start) printf(", ");
        start = 1;
        val = record[fields[key]];
        if (val) printf("%s", val);
        else printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more.

```
function dump() { if (a[1]!="") print a[1],a[2],a[3]; a[2]=a[3]=""; }; 
BEGIN { RS="Field"; OFS=", "; a[1]=a[2]=a[3]="" } 
END {dump()}
{ if ($1=="1") dump(); a[$1]=$2; }
```